# Error Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sintaxis

Hola estoy mostrando la consulta en la base de datos con un while donde multiplico los datos entre dos columnas y me arroja la notice del titulo. Hace el calculo bien pero muestra esa notice, como la quito? el "@" no me funciona aquí

```
          <label>
            <h6>' . $columP['cantidad'] * $columP['subtotal'] . '$</h6>
          </label>
```

Comment: Con esos datos poco podremos ayudarte. Mira de depurar el código tu mismo a ver que consigues ver de raro en los valores de esas claves de ese array mediante un var_dump().  Léete [ask], el [tour] y lo del [example] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio, cómo hacer buenas preguntas y cómo darnos un ejemplo válido para poderte ayudar con buenas respuestas, gracias.

Comment: Error estaba en la base de datos. Tenia el valor de tipo de columna como "varchar" cuando debe ser "int". Di con la respuesta en Stack overflow Original (en ingles), donde la pregunta era mucho mas corta que la mía... Gracias.

Comment: Si te refieres a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6136430/10382744) fíjate en el tercer comentario de la pregunta. Dice lo que yo te he dicho (mismo enlace al [example] inglés), y agrega que "esta página está repleta de conjeturas descabelladas sobre la solución correcta. Este lío no es agradable para los que buscan la solución".  Es decir, los que responden intentan adivinar que le pasa al que pregunta, pues no tienen suficientes datos. Lo siento si te has ofendido, me parece notarlo en tu ironia sobre lo corta que era la pregunta, pero fijate que nadie te ha contestado aqui.

Comment: Y si no te han contestado aquí será porque la pregunta no se entendía sin más contexto y nadie (y ni tu ni yo) se ha tomado ni la molestia de buscar ese mensaje de error en google, donde ese enlace a la página en inglés aparece el primero. Los enlaces que te dí son para ayudarte, no me malinterpretes, y se los damos siempre a los nuevos colaboradores cuando detectamos que desconocen como funciona el sitio, y para que aprendan a plantear mejores preguntas para obtener las mejores respuestas. Dicho esto, solo me queda recordarte este enlace sobre el [tour] que aun no has visitado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en la base de datos. Tenia el valor de tipo de columna como "varchar" cuando debe ser "int".

El tipo de datos VARCHAR almacena series de caracteres de hasta 255 bytes en un campo de longitud variable. Los datos pueden consistir en letras, números y símbolos.

El tipo INTEGER es un tipo estándar de SQL para representar números enteros.

Para la maquina, estaba intentando hacer cálculos aritméticos con letras y símbolos, aunque los registros eran todos números. Cambie el tipo a "int" y listo.